# How to detect two-finger tap in Android?

Tags: android, multi-touch, gesture

I need to detect two-finger tap in an `Android` app I'm working on. I'm also using `ScaleGestureDetector` and `GestureDetector` to detect tap, double-tap, long press and scale.

In my `onTouchEvent` method I have:

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        activePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    .
    .
    .
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());

        if (pointerId == activePointerId) {
            // change active pointer
        } else if (!scaleDetector.isInProgress() && (event.getPointerCount() == 2)) {
            // handle two-finger tap
        }
        break;
    .
    .
    .
```

The problem is that scale is also detected as a two-finger tap. Any ideas about fixing this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also had encountered such a problem before. Finally I had to write my own class which extends GestureDetector.And you can  implement scale by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int tap_count=0;
    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        switch(action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : {

                ++tap_count;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN "+tap_count);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : {
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN : {

                ++tap_count;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN "+tap_count);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP : {

                ++tap_count;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP "+tap_count);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : {

                --tap_count;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP "+tap_count);

                if(tap_count == 2){
                    tap_count = 0;
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Enableing Accessbility",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
        }
```